# How can I add a delay between two messages in the AWS SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

folks. I'm developing a live stream app like TikTok, twitch and we use AWS services for this project. But I'm struggling with a problem right now. I receive gifts from users during live streams and show them on the screen. Here is the problem: When two users send gifts at the same time, the gift appears on top of the other on the screen. I used AWS SQS for this problem. But I couldn't add a specific delay time in between gifts. I also used the FIFO queue type. I need logic which is if there is a gift in the queue, another gift will show after 10 seconds. Could you help me with it?

Comment: You should probably manage this on your front-end rather than AWS imo

Comment: maybe share how the SQS queue is sending data to the plugin/front-end that's showing the notifications?

Comment: What is retrieving messages from the Amazon SQS queue? Or do you have it automatically invoking an AWS Lambda message whenever a message is sent to SQS? More details, please.